# Parallel Foreach vs PLINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, task-parallel-library, plinq

Id like to know the pros and cons of Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ. 
Also are they related - does one of them calls/depends on the other internally

How do you take decisions on what to use?

Comment: Please take a look at : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/21/9997559.aspx

Comment: This looks like a useful reading. Thanks!